# Create a 3D surface with THREE.js given an SVG path

Tags: svg, three.js

How do I create a 3D surface given an SVG path.
I'd like this surface to be create by the rotation of the path around an axis.

[image]

I use SVGLoader to load my SVG; It's like an extrude on rotation. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

```
const loader = new SVGLoader();

loader.load(

    'data/svgSample.svg',

    function ( data ) {

        const paths = data.paths;
        const group = new THREE.Group();

        for ( let i = 0; i < paths.length; i ++ ) {

            const path = paths[ i ];

            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                color: path.color,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                depthWrite: false
            } );

            const shapes = path.toShapes( true );

            for ( let j = 0; j < shapes.length; j ++ ) {

                const shape = shapes[ j ];
                const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( shape );
                const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                group.add( mesh );

            }

        }
        scene.add( group );
    }
);
```

Comment: Have a look at LatheGeometry in the docs.

Comment: Yup, It works using LatheGeometry. I'll post the solution later